# Connection between the integral of a functional and the functional of the integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $f \in C_\infty(\mathbb{R^2})$ be a function and $V: C_\infty(\mathbb{R^2}) \to C_\infty(\mathbb{R^2})$ a functional acting on the space where $f$ is defined.

I was wondering if there is any kind of relationship between the objects

$$\int V[f(x,y)] dx \quad \text{and} \quad V \left[ \int f(x,y) dx \right] $$

If $V$ is a linear functional I understand the relationship between these two objects but I don't know if there is any in the general case. Is there any reference or counter example that shows (or disproves) how these two objects are connected?

In particular I was looking for a way of expressing

$$\int V[f(x,y)] dx = \tilde{V} \left[ \int f(x,y)dx \right] $$

Where $\tilde{V}[\cdot]$ is defined in terms of $V$.

Comment: If your integrals are definite integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ then $\int f(x)dx$  on the right side is a constant.

Comment: If, for instance, $V(f)=f^2$, then you would basically be looking for an equality relation between the $L^2$ norm of a function, and a function of its $L^1$ norm. I doubt such thing exists.

Comment: I guess with $\int f(x)\,dx$ you mean an anti-derivative of $f$. But this is only defined up ti constants. So, you should require $V$ to map constants to zero. But actually, I don't really get what you would like to ask.

Comment: You should specify whether you want definite integrals or indefinite integrals. In the first case, I only have an idea for bounded intervals, and that is that if $V$ is convex, you have Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I made a big mistake when writing down the function and its definition. I am interested in $f(x,y)$ so that the definite integral over $x$ is still a function only of $y$ in this case.